# Symfony2 doctrine query to get data from 3 tables

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-user-bundle

I am using Symfony Sonata User bundle for user management. I have created another entity as `LoginHistory` with `OneToMany` relationship between `User` and `LoginHistory`

I have to display the list of all users using KNP Paginator Bundle with their group name (normally belongs to one group only) with detail login history.

I have wrote this query, but it didn't get the group data of users.

```
 $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('u')
                     ->join('PNCLogBundle:LoginHistory', 'log', 'WITH log.User = u.id')
                     ->innerJoin('u.groups', 'g')
                     ->andwhere('g.id = u.group')
                     ->where('u.roles LIKE :roles')
                     ->setParameter('roles', '%"ROLE_STAFF"%')
                     ->getQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

> There are 2 types of JOINs: **“Regular”** Joins and **“Fetch”** Joins.

What you need is a fetch-join. You can read on this [in the doctrine2 documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins). The solution is simple, just add `g` to your select clause in the query builder:

```
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->select('u', 'g')
                    ->join('PNCLogBundle:LoginHistory', 'log', 'WITH log.User = u.id')
                    ->innerJoin('u.groups', 'g')
                    ->andwhere('g.id = u.group')
                    ->where('u.roles LIKE :roles')
                    ->setParameter('roles', '%"ROLE_STAFF"%')
                    ->getQuery();
```

You can also use the `addSelect` method:

```
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->addSelect('g')
                    ->join('PNCLogBundle:LoginHistory', 'log', 'WITH log.User = u.id')
                    ->innerJoin('u.groups', 'g')
                    ->andwhere('g.id = u.group')
                    ->where('u.roles LIKE :roles')
                    ->setParameter('roles', '%"ROLE_STAFF"%')
                    ->getQuery();
```

Comment: Got error that `Error: Expected Literal, got 'JOIN'`

Comment: This is not related to what I added in my answer, I think it is because of your join clause `->join('PNCLogBundle:LoginHistory', 'log', 'WITH log.User = u.id')`...  [Check google you will find enough answers to solve that](https://www.google.com/webhp#q=Error%3A+Expected+Literal%2C+got+'JOIN'). You should probably do something like `->join('u.logs', 'log')`